# How to use table control to update records in database?

Tags: database, controls, abap

I've created Table control which is used while entering data. Data will flow from table control to internal table and then to the database. For reading data into internal table, subroutines will be used. Currently I'm stuck in building Table Control logic. There are 8 rows displayed initially in TC, after 1st row is filled and user presses enter, the data inside TC is gone. I tried debugging default SAP program's to check their logic, but the naming convention is confusing me a lot. Another issue is of blank row. Suppose the user enters value in 4th row (keeping the 3rd row blank) the row should move UP automatically after user click's enter.

Any solution for the above problem ? Or any useful link which I can refer ?

Comment: In its current form, your question cannot really be answered with a single answer. Please keep in mind that SO is a Q&A format, not a general discussion board.

Comment: sorry, will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the internal table for the table control is declared as a global variable, ensure you populate the data stored in this internal table to your table control at PBO time.

Please provide some coding to get a clue what exactly you are doing.

Comment: And please ensure you store the filled-in data into your internal table at PAI runtime so SAP can fetch it from there in the next PBO-PAI cycle.